# Uploading all my files to GitHub

Tags: linux, git

I created a new repo on github called [GHide](https://github.com/osamarao/GHide). The repo is completely empty. I read the instructions on github for a hello-world repo. But I can't find out how I can upload my existing GHide files from my computer to the GitHub repo.
How is that to be done. I am using Linux so command-line `git` commands will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to set up `git`, as explained [here](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/). Next, you'll need to create a local copy of the repo and add files to it. It's explained in detail [here](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/), but this should do what you need:

```
mkdir GHide
cd GHide
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:osamarao/GHide.git
# At this point, copy your existing files into the GHide folder.
git add .
git commit -m 'Adding initial files.'
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: what this "." represent in "git add ." ?

Comment: The `.` represents the current directory. It basically tells `git add` to add all of the current directory.

Comment: Since you've added `origin` manually (rather than by cloning) you probably also want to make that `git push -u origin master`, in order to set up the association between your `master` and the `master` in your `origin` repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get permission and authed:

```
git config --global user.email "yourusername@gmail.com"

Remove-Item ".git" -Recurse -Force
git init
git add .
git commit -m “Test132”
git remote add github https://github.com/yourusername/nuxtjs_typescript.git
git remote -v
git push -f github master
Remove-Item ".git" -Recurse -Force
```

Copy this and good to go